# PHP Script exceeds memory limit for database SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I am referring to this code, that I've been writing:

https://github.com/sharedRoutine/PHP-Scripts/blob/master/class.dbmanager.php#L295

This line is being logged into the error.log when I am opening the website. It loads a huge amount of data (more than 120k) entries.

so mysqli_stmt_fetch is called quite often. and for each entry an object will be created and pushed onto an array.

Is there anything I can do to optimize this code? Make it use less memory. I know there are methods to increase the memory and there is also clone, however I can't use it since my every call to mysqli_stmt_fetch will set the $row properties which are passed by reference.

Alternatively, for this call, I could use a COUNT statement instead of SELECT, however I am trying to fix a possible memory leak.

Even this code has the same issue:

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($prep)) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
        $obj->$value = $row->$value;
    }
    array_push($resultArray,$obj);
    unset($obj); //unset the object
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

- xCoder (sharedRoutine)

Comment: Implement pagination. Chances are you are attempting to hydrate thousands of objects at once.

Comment: how could it use less memory? you're fetching the entire result set into memory. either retrieve less data, or don't suck in all of it at once. that or increase php's memory limit, which only defers the problem if your data set is growing. And note that your foreach loop is poinjtless. mysqli can fetch into an object directly, no need to copy from a result array into an object yourself.

Comment: There is no memory leak. There's memory **shortage**. That's a huge difference, and the shortage comes from you trying to add more water than the cup can hold. The only possible solution is that you don't add as much water. Simple, right?

Comment: Did my answer solve your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/34797903/3822464 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need them all stored in memory and can't just get less entries at once, an approach you could do as a last resort would be to store in the array a serialized+compressed string of each object and then unserialize+uncompress as needed.

See http://php.net/zlib and http://php.net/serialize

As a tip, if you compressed groups of serialized objects (like had subarrays of 100 objects each and serialized+compressed each subarray), that could result in even greater memory savings.

I don't advocate this as a recommended approach as it will introduce complexity and use additional CPU to compress/uncompress, but if you have no other option and must keep them in memory, it's a possible solution.

Comment: Sadly, incorrect. Compress all you like, sticking entire data set into whatever is a stupid idea. You can still run out of memory to hold data. The only solution is not to fetch everything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php). The advantage is that they yield each element instead of writing them all to system memory.

```
function my_object_generator($prep) {
    while ($info=mysqli_stmt_fetch($prep)) {
        $obj = new stdClass();
        foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
            $obj->$value = $row->$value;
        }
        yield $obj;
    }
}

$read_transformed_data = my_object_generator($prep);
foreach ($foo in $read_transformed_data) {
   print($foo);
}
```

One advantage is that you do not need to handle your data in chunks. 
One disadvantage is that you can't count the length the data. But on heavy data sets one should use mysql counting functions for that purpose. Also be aware that you do not collect the generator output into another array again. This would lead to the same problem as before.

Answer (score -1):

use PDO instead of mysqli and do this:

```
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

gives you an array of objects with column names as keys (and db values as values).
Pretty neat .. no while loop required

Comment: And that stops memory consumption how?

Comment: I would just try it in the hopes, that the internal memory usage magic of php works better than my own. The rest of your DbManager should work with it as far as I could see from a quick glance. But maybe I am too optimisitvc in both sentences.

Comment: Sadly, it's the same thing. There are two options - `SplFixedArray` or `Judy` array, it might lower the consumption. However, the only sane move is not to fetch the entire database into php which has memory limits in place :)